# set library path for current script

Tags: linux, shell-script, environment-variables, libraries, dynamic-linking

How can I set the library path for the current script that's running? I mean I don't want to list a new path for the libraries in a textfile.
I tried it using `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/lib/`

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(pwd)/lib/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./X3TC_config
```

Comment: Do you really mean `$(pwd)`, or do you mean `$(dirname $0)`?

Comment: I mean $(pwd) .

Comment: The script you've posted does exactly what you're asking. If that's not working for you, tell us where the libraries are located, what the current directory is when you start the script, and copy-paste the error messages complaining of a missing library. I suspect that [you're asking the wrong question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but I can't tell what the right question would be with so little information.

Comment: The libs are in the lib folder but it still says it cant find the "libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0" library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your script, these two lines close to the top should do the trick:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(pwd)/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Although `bash` allows you to set and export a variable in a single statement, not all shells do, so the two step approach is more portable, if that's a concern.

If this isn't working for you, check that you are running the script from the right place - using `$(pwd)` like this ties you to running the script from the directory that contains the required `./lib` subdirectory.

If you want to be able to run the script from anywhere, you need to use the absolute path to the `./lib` subdir, or construct a relative path from the directory portion of the path to the script using, e.g., `$(dirname $0)`

Comment: It still says it can't the required "libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0" although it is in the folder.

Comment: What is the command you are trying to call? Does it care about the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: chmod +x testandlaunch
./testandlaunch

Comment: Is `testandlaunch` the program you are trying to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for, or the script you are trying to modify to make that happen? It might help if you post the relevant parts of your script as an edit to your question.

Comment: It's the script.

Answer (score 1):

you should execute you program in this way:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/lib/ <your_executable_here>
```

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is arguably slightly better - you only need it once in the script, and anything you call that cares about it will find it. No repetition, reduced scope for errors. You can override an existing setting with an inline assignment, if necessary.

Comment: @D_Bye, probably. But if you need this setting only for this script your way will mess other programs

Comment: This doesn't change anything for the script that is running (which is what the OP asks for), only for a new invocation.

Comment: Do you mean with <your_execition_here> a library?

Comment: No, by <your_executable_here> i mean the program you run. If its for example script, named testscript.sh the command will become: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/lib/ testscript.sh

Comment: I use the following script: "#!/bin/bash


export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/lib/


./X3TC_config"
To run a game outside from steam.

Comment: No, @nifker. The way i offer you above is different. Set of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is done outside the script. It set temporary the variable to have this value, execute the script and return the original value of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Isn't it possible to set library path in the script?

Comment: It is possible to export a variable in a script, so that it only affects calls made within that script. Once the shell started by the kernel to run the script dies, so does its context - including any variables you export. I should have made that clearer in my comment.

Comment: Yes, you can do it by executing your script on this way: . /path/to/script.sh This will run the script in current shell

Comment: I tried to run it like that but it says it can't find the libraries that are in the lib folder

Comment: This way is only if you have the set of variable inside the script